# Nautilus file permissions on mounted folder

Tags: 18.04, permissions, nautilus, fstab, sshfs

I've mounted a remote server on my local machine by adding

`remoteusername@remote.ip:/ /mnt/remotename fuse.sshfs  IdentityFile=/home/localusername/.ssh/id_rsa    delay_connect   _netdev,allow_other,idmap=user  0   0`

to my /etc/fstab

I can see  that the mount succeeded when I do:

`sudo ls /mnt/remotename`

When I open nautilus as sudo I can browse the mounted folder, when I open nautilus as my local user I cannot browse the mounted folder: `Permission denied` . Not very surprising, but annoying.

Is there a way for me to allow nautilus to browse these folders without having  to `sudo nautilus` first? Or to mount it in such a way that these permission issues don't arise?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Edit:

Changed my fstab to:

`remoteusername@remote:/    /mnt/remote fuse.sshfs      _netdev,allow_other,users   0   0`

Booting no longer mounts the remote, when running `sudo mount -a` the server prompts me for my password and mounting succeeds and permissions are correct so that my local user can access the mount. How do I set it up so that my ssh key pair, which is already set up, is used to identify me? So that on boot it can automount and have the correct permisisons.

Comment: `sudo chown foo:foo /mnt/remotename` where `foo` si your username

Comment: The above gives `chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/remote': Permission denied`

Comment: I think that `chmod` won't work neither.

Purhaps that your question is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/273687/how-can-i-mount-a-remote-volume-with-777-permissions-for-all-users

Comment: Your link seems to suggest to have influence on the standard permissions set when a user creates a new file on remote. I'm still stuck at giving my local user the rights to read and write files on remote.